# jsGrid - what is the best way to style grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jsgrid

I am trying to style JSGrid (js-grid.com).
At first I tried to override style rules in css file, but this method is not good. It's not flexible.

For example checkbox.
I have default checkbox, but for example I want to style it like material design icons (mdi).

On initial loading, I want checkbox looks like mdi. In documentation there is a `rowRenderer(item, itemIndex)` method, but inside this method I get my record object only

```
{
    "provider": "Jon Doe",
    "service": "UPS",
    "name": "Jon Doe Name",
    "region": "Region 1",
    "schedule": "1 Day",
    "cet": "23:59",
    "dwo": "09:00",
    "dwc": "23:59",
    "disabled": false
}
```

My last field "disabled" - checkbox and I want to style it.
But inside method I know only that it could be true/false, how to render a label before it, or set some class?

Here is my fields config:

```
fields: [

   {
       name: "disabled",
       type: "checkbox",
       title: "Disabled",
       editing: true,
       visible: true
   },
]
```

Comment: For example when I click on row to edit - jsGrid simply creates an empty checkbox in by Disabled field - but I want it to be styled

Comment: Put in the object to be rendered a checkbox with style.

Comment: didn't understand, sorry

Comment: each field has `css` option in the config (http://js-grid.com/docs/#fields). Set your css class to this option and add styling to the css stylesheet.

Comment: @tabalin, `filtercss` is not working for me.